# Which cmap (colormap) to use with matplotlib imshow() to diplay the MNIST dataset images as black characters on white background

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, mnist

The original MNIST images are white background with grayscale characters on them.  0 represents white and 255 is black, in-between are shades of gray.  I'm using a copy of data set provided by `keras` which uses the same format.

Just to look at things, I'm using `matplotlib` to display examples from data set, but when I choose a cmap of `'gray'`, I get black background with white characters like below.

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  plt.imshow(X_train[0], cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Is there another colormap that will correctly display the images as black on a white background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either [invert the colormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html?highlight=colormaps#matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps) (using the `*_r` version of your colormap) or invert (negate) your data.

```
# Invert the colormap
plt.imshow(X_train[0], cmap='gray_r')

# Invert your data
plt.imshow(-X_train[0], cmap='gray')
```